# How to detect URLs written or pasted in a RichTextBox in WPF application

Tags: wpf, url, richtextbox

Sometimes a user will type a website URL while chatting in a Chat Application. I need to make the RichTextBox detect these URLs automatically, but I do not know how. General TextBox does not detect URLs, so i have used  RichTextBox instead. I know RichTextBoxes can detect URLs but I don't know how. Can anybody suggest how I might do this?

Comment: Look for `http://` or `https://`.

Answer (score 2):

As schoola pointed out, the WPF RichTextBox does not auto-detect URLs. However [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prajakta/archive/2006/10/17/autp-detecting-hyperlinks-in-richtextbox-part-i.aspx) describes a fairly simple (150 line) implementation of a custom RichTextBox that can be used for this very purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The WPF RichTextBox does not support auto-detection of URLs, but the Windows Forms Rich Text Box does. You might use a WindowsFormsHost element in your WPF application like this:

```
[...]
xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms" 
[...]

<WindowsFormsHost >
    <wf:RichTextBox DetectUrls="True" />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

Comment: Thanks schoola for your helpful concern,but the WindowsFormsHost element is not recognised and shows that 'A value of type RichTextBox cannot be adde to a collection or dictionary of type UIElementCollection'.Could you tell me how to make it work.