# Textbox text link to an external website

Tags: c#

How can i make the text in a `TextBox` or a `RichTextBox` link to a url of my choice?

How can I make a text portion in a `TextBox` as a hyperlink, so when the text is clicked it will open a browser with to the URL of my choice?

In my particular example this is the issue:
I have a text box with a lot of words, between each word is a new line, I want to make each word link to a specific website. How would i go about doing this?

Comment: Can you provide more context?  What type of app are you talking about?   Web? Winforms?  Also, what do you mean by `make text link to a url`?  Do you mean that the text is clickable?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming WinForms:

Set the `DetectUrls` ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.detecturls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) property to *true*, then handle the `LinkClicked` event ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.linkclicked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
richTextBox.DetectUrls = true;
richTextBox.LinkClicked += (sender, e) => {
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.LinkText);
};
```

Comment: It is worth noting that this is a `WinForms` approach. If this is WPF you will need to use an alternative approach. There is a thread over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124429/how-to-detect-urls-written-or-pasted-in-a-richtextbox-in-wpf-application that discusses how it is done in WPF. Although the thread then references external blogs to discuss how it can be done.

Comment: Hope you could help me... I doubt i'll be getting an answer from anyone else unless i open another question.

Answer (score 0):

you can link to a URL with any control event with `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(textbox.Text);`

Comment: This does not answer the question. Consider an edit to answer the OP question of 'How can i make the text in a TextBox or a RichTextBox link to a url of my choice?`